# Getting Array Data from Image File in Swift

Tags: swift, pointers, swift5, cgimage, rgba

I've searched around and found various ways of getting array data from an image.  I've picked examples of CGImage setup and arrived now on some code that produces the output I expect.  Leave for one problem.
**Issue:**

For whatever reason, my code initializes the arrays with zeros, and after the for loop, any indices past ~1000 are still zero.  For every single array the red, green, blue, and alpha values all look as expected until this value >1000, and then are all zero!

Have a look at my code and please help me debug this.

```
func forLoopWay() -> [[UInt8]] {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    print("for loop way")
    let Image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let image: CGImage = Image!.cgImage!
    
    let width = image.width
    let height = image.height
    let colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bytesPerRow = (4 * width);
    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    var pixels = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: width * height * 4 )

    let context = CGContext.init(data: pixels,
                                 width: width,
                                 height: height,
                                 bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
                                 bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                                 space: colorspace,
                                 bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)

    context?.draw(image, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height)))
    
    var alpha = [UInt8].init(repeating: 0, count: width * height)
    var red = [UInt8].init(repeating: 0, count: width * height)
    var green = [UInt8].init(repeating: 0, count: width * height)
    var blue = [UInt8].init(repeating: 0, count: width * height)

    let test_val = pixels.pointee
    print(test_val)
    print( pixels.pointee)
    for x in 0..<width {
        for y in 0..<height {
        red[x + y]    = pixels.pointee
        pixels = pixels + 1
        green[x + y]      = pixels.pointee
        pixels = pixels + 1
        blue[x + y]    = pixels.pointee
        pixels = pixels + 1
        alpha[x + y]     = pixels.pointee
            pixels = pixels + 1
      }
    }
    
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print("Time elapsed \(String(format : "%0.5f", timeElapsed)) seconds")
    print()
    return [red, green, blue, alpha]
}
```

I've set a breakpoint before the return and tried this debug.  My image is 512 x 512, so it makes no sense for the linear index 1100 to be zero.

```
(lldb) print alpha[1003]
(UInt8) $R3 = 255
(lldb) print alpha[1010]
(UInt8) $R4 = 255
(lldb) print alpha[1100]
(UInt8) $R5 = 0
(lldb) print red[1010]
(UInt8) $R6 = 75
(lldb) print red[1010]
(UInt8) $R7 = 75
(lldb) print red[1100]
(UInt8) $R8 = 0
(lldb) print red[1003]
(UInt8) $R9 = 75
(lldb) print red[10]
(UInt8) $R10 = 161
```

Comment: You should structure your data. I mean your `Pixel`

Comment: I made a stupid math error.  I fixed it by introducing `var linearOffset = 0` and incrementing in each iteration. and replacing x + y with this.  Total nooby error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it when I switch on the other half of my brain.

```
var linearOffset = 0
for x in 0..<width {
    for y in 0..<height {
        red[linearOffset] = pixels.pointee
        pixels += 1
        green[linearOffset] = pixels.pointee
        pixels += 1
        blue[linearOffset] = pixels.pointee
        pixels += 1
        alpha[linearOffset] = pixels.pointee
        pixels += 1
        linearOffset +=1 
    }
}
```